# Writing char array to file, with escape characters written with their corresponding literals

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a char array to file, the the escaped characters should be written with their equivalent literals (for example newline should be written as '\n' instead of actual line break in the file).

if the array is `char *arr = "hello world\n";`
my code should write

```
char tempArr[100] ={'h','e','l','l','o','\s','w','o','r','l','d','\n'};
```

to the file.

is there any way to accomplish this in C++?

Comment: Of course there’s a way, and it’s actually very trivial. It would help if you could show us what you’ve tried, and where precisely your problems lie.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `'\n'` as one of your characters, you can have both `'\\'` and `'n'`.

To be clear, I mean for you to put both `'\\'` and `'n'` in your array.  That way, both `'\'` and `'n'` are printed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is a C solution:

```
void printAndEscapeString(const char *input, FILE *output)
{
    const char escapeCodes[] = {
        '\n',
        '\t',
        '\v',
        '\'',
        '\"',
        '\?',
        '\a',
        '\b',
        '\f',
        '\r',
    };

    const char escapeReplacements[] = {
        'n',
        't',
        'v',
        '\'',
        '\"',
        '?',
        'a',
        'b',
        'f',
        'r',
    };

    while (*input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(escapeCodes); i++) {
            if (*input == escapeCodes[i])
            {
                putc('\\', output);
                putc(escapeReplacements[i], output);

                goto NEXT; // use goto because I'm too lazy to figure out a better way
            }
        }

        fputc(*input, output);

    NEXT:
        input++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know of a way of doing this in standard C.

```
FILE *fp;

int check = 0;

fp = fopen("output.txt", "w");
fprintf(fp, "%s", "char tempArr[100] = {");
for (i = 0; arr[i]; i++)
{
    if (i)
        fputc(',', fp);
    check += 4;
    fputc('\'', fp);
    switch(arr[i])
    {
        case '\n':
            check++;
            fputc('\\', fp);
            fputc('n', fp);
            break;
        // ...
        default:
            fputc(arr[i], fp);
    }
}
fprintf(fp, "%s", "};\n");
if (check >= 100)
    fprintf(stderr, "WARNING: tempArr contains MORE than 100 characters!\n");
```